# Store spinner item in sqlite and get it in another spinner

Tags: android, sqlite, android-spinner

How can I store the selected item of the spinner1 in the sqlite and retrieve it in spinner2 of another activity?

I've tried `spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString();` and storing it in sqlite. But the problem is, setting it for spinner2 is not possible because you cannot set text in the spinner.

I'm thinking of using `spinner1.getSelectedItemPosition();` and store the position int in sqlite. But how can I use that int to set the position for spinner2?

Or is there a much better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But how can I use that int to set the position for spinner2?

Use [`setSelection(int)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsSpinner.html#setSelection%28int%29).

Answer (score 1):

save spinner position in database  and get it in another spinner. But for that you have to use same spinner array in both the spinner.

```
int spnPos =  spinner1.getSelectedItemPosition();
```

and set in second spinner

```
spinner2.setSelection(spnPos);
```